# Lenovo laptop keyboard not working

Tags: windows-10, drivers, keyboard, touchpad, lenovo-laptop

I would ask you for help. I have laptop Lenovo E560 with Windows 10 1803. Suddenly keyboard and touchpad has stopped working. USB keyboard and mouse works properly. In device manager I saw exclamation mark near Ultranav touchpad. I have tried reinstall drivers (downloaded from Lenovo support), then update to Windows 1809, but nothing helps. Keyboard works properly in BIOS and also in Live Linux. So I have decided to reinstall Windows. But the keyboard and touchpad does not work even in Windows installer from brand new ISO downloaded from MS! I have tried older release of Windows 10, then Windows 7 - all the same! I have updated BIOS to latest availiable with no progress. I have already read whole internet, many people have the same problem with Lenovo notebooks, but I have not found working solution for me. Vendor of keyboard/touchpad is ALPS.